# If the Dirichlet series $L(z,\chi)$ diverges for $\sigma< 1$, does its alternating version converge for some $\sigma_0 < 1$, and conversely?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, limits-and-convergence, dirichlet-series

Here $\chi$ is a completely multiplicative function with $\chi(p)\in\{-1,+1\}$ for any prime $p$, but not necessarily a character. Also $s=\sigma + it$ as usual. The series corresponding to $L(s,\chi)$ is the expansion of the Euler product
$$\prod_{p\in P} \frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k^s}$$
where $P$ is an infinite subset of primes (or the full set), and $2\in P$. The product is ordered by increasing values of $p$. The $\eta(s,\chi)$ series is the alternating version:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{a_k}{k^s}
$$
When $\sigma>1$ and everything converges nicely, we have:
$\eta(s,\chi)=(1-2^{1-s})L(s,\chi)$. Note that $a_k\in\{-1,0,+1\}$.

The goal is to obtain a partial analytic continuation of one series (usually not to the full complex plane) when the other one (its alternating version) converges over a larger domain. The fundamental example is when $\chi(p)=1$. Then $L$ is the Riemann zeta function defined for $\sigma>1$ due to convergence limitations ($a_k=1$), while $\eta$ is the Dirichlet eta function defined (via the aternating series) for
$\sigma > 0$.

The purpose is to work more easily with some $\chi$ that causes one of the two series to have a smaller domain of convergence than its alternating version. Or is it possible that both series have abscissa of convergence $\sigma=1$, depending on $\chi$?

Comment: You are mixing up both $z$ and $s$ as complex variables in a Dirichlet series. Stick to just one letter: $s$. It is not usual to write $z=\sigma + it$, but instead $s=\sigma+it$.

Comment: @KConrad: thanks, I made the change.

Comment: Why should this true outside of the RZ case? If your coefficients already change signs infinitely many times why should introducing a fairly arbitrary $(-1)^n$ based on parity change anything? In the RZ case there is a clear reason why $\eta$ works better, while in the non principal real character cases already the Dirichlet series converges for $\Re s  > 0$ because already the $a_k$ alternate well enough

Comment: @Conrad: I am not saying this should happen outside RZ or other "relatively well balanced" series. Actually, I was hoping for a negative answer: this would allow me not to waste my time on a path going to nowhere.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site. Is your main question the last sentence? Also, there are some typos in your post. $a_k$ should be $\chi(k)$, while $1-2^{1-s}$ should be $1-\chi(2)2^{1-s}$.

Comment: I thought the last sentence and my question were one and the same, stated in two different ways. I'll check the $\chi(2)$. But I believe $a_k$ can't be $\chi(k)$ because $P$ does not necessarily contain all primes. If $3\notin P$, then $a_3, a_6, a_9$ and so on are all zero, and $\chi(3)$ is undefined.

Comment: **1.** Restricting to $P$ is the same as allowing zero values for $\chi(p)$, namely $\chi(p)=0$ for $p\not\in P$. So you should simply say that $\chi(p)\in\{-1,0,1\}$, and then $a_k=\chi(k)$, and the condition $p\in P$ can be removed. **2.** Note also that the symbol $\chi$ is usually reserved for characters (including higher degree characters of non-abelian Galois groups), while the symbol $L(s,\cdot)$ is reserved for true $L$-functions (satisfying a functional equation etc.). **3.** The only question in your post is the last sentence, and it starts with "Or". This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thanks, will have to update my notations moving forward. I need to make more efforts to use the most standard notations, and avoid confusing notations. Part of my learning curve. In the end, my question is this: can you find a counter-example to what I mentioned in the question at the top.

Comment: Not clear what you want a counterexample to. Is your question the last sentence?

Comment: Either way is fine. If my question is subject to multiple interpretations, an answer to the easiest version is OK and will be just as useful to me. Also, the reason I use a subset of $P$ rather than allowing $\chi$ to be zero is because I plan to extend this to "pseudo-primes" that may not be integers, or not even numbers (say, commuting matrices or Beurling primes). I would then have to use a suitable $\chi$. That said, the notations involving all elements of the parent set (whatever they might be) would probably work there, along with $\chi=0$ for missing elements in $P$.

Comment: It is not that your question is subject to multiple interpretations. It is not clear what your question is in the first place. Is it the last sentence in your post, is this what you want to ask? A rule of thumb is that each new entry at this website should be about a clear and well-defined question (a single question).

Comment: Generally, this is impossible. Indeed, for Dirichlet $L$-series with poles (from the right) of order at least 2 at $s=1$, this actually impossible. The alternating Dirichlet series would still diverge at $s=1$.